# Retrieve whole document from couchbase lite in phonegap

Tags: cordova, couchbase-lite

I am newbie to couchbase lite and I need your help.
   I want to store the data and access in offline and displayed in the phonegap app. So I am choosing the couchbase lite.

Use sample code to do some step.There are

- Add the couchbase lite framework.
- Run it in the phonegap app.
- Get the Local couchbase lite URL.
- Create database.
- Database connection to insert, update and delete the document.

  **But my problem retrieves the whole document from the database**.
  At the same time I read the map method to retrive the document. but i am not able to understand.

  Sample Phonegap app:[Here the link](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/ToDoLite-PhoneGap)

  Below I have attached the working code, test it in the ios platform

  ```
   var coax = require("coax");
   console.log(coax);
   var appDbName = "couchdb";
   document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

  // deviceready Event Handler
  //
  // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
  // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'

  function onDeviceReady() {
  receivedEvent('deviceready');
  setupConfig(function(err){
              if (err) {
              alert(err)
              return console.log("err "+JSON.stringify(err))
              }
              });

  }

  function logMessage(message) {
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerHTML = message;
  document.body.getElementsByClassName('app')[0].appendChild(p);
  console.log(message);
  }

   // Update DOM on a Received Event

  function receivedEvent(id) {
  var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
  var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
  var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

  listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
  receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

  console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
  }



  function setupConfig(done) {
  // get CBL url
  if (!window.cblite) {
      return done('Couchbase Lite not installed')
  }
  cblite.getURL(function(err, url) {
                console.log("getURL: " + JSON.stringify([err, url]));

                window.server = coax(url);

                var db = coax([url, appDbName]);

                setupDb(db, function(err, info){
                        console.log("getDB"+db);

                        if (err) {
                        return alert( JSON.stringify("GetDB:"+ err ) );
                        }

                        db.get("_local/user", function(err, doc) {
                          if (err) {

                              if( err.status == 404 ) {


                              var docV = { "key" : "value" };
                              db.put( "_local/user", docV, function( err, ok ) {
                              //HERE I AM INSERT THE DATA
                              return alert( JSON.stringify("Success:" + ok ) );
                              } );


                              }
                              else {
                              return alert( JSON.stringify( err ) );
                              }

                          }
                          else {
                              console.log("Document : "+doc._id);
                              // HERE I AM UPDATE AND DELETE THE DATA
                              doc._deleted =true;
                              db.put("_local/user", doc, function(error, ok) {

                              });


                              }

                        });


                        });

                });

  }

    function setupDb(db, cb) {
          db.get(function(err, res, body){
           console.log(JSON.stringify(["before create db put", err, res, body]))
           db.put(function(err, res, body){
                db.get(cb);
                })
           })
   }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You get the doc passed in as a JS var.  Here's a small snippet that shows this (from the sample app you linked):

```
function toggleChecked(id) {
    log("toggle", id)
    config.db.get(id, function(err, doc){
        doc.checked = !doc.checked
        doc.updated_at = new Date()
        config.db.put(id, doc, function(){})
    })
}
```

Properties in doc are available and updated directly.